# read the elements and add the unique elements in other object

Tags: java, java-8

I have the below sample code.

```
 List<MyItemsData.GroupItemInfo> itemsList = new ArrayList<>();
    //some business logic to add the MyItemsData objects in the itemsList.
    itemsList.stream().forEach(groupItemInfo -> {
                if (groupItemInfo.getItems().isEmpty()) {
                    System.out.println("item is null");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("item not null " + groupItemInfo.getItems().size());
                }
                if (!groupItemInfo.getItems().isEmpty()) {
    
                }
            });
```

I want to store all the items from all objects whose type!=null and should be unique(duplicates should not be allowed)

Comment: where are the values initially ? What variable is shown in your debug screenshot ?

Answer (score 1):

To keep only the element whose `items` aren't empty, from your code with minimal modifications

```
List<MyItemsData> result = ...; // initial data
List<MyItemsData> itemWithNotEmptyItems = new ArrayList<>();

result.forEach(groupItemInfo -> {
    if (!groupItemInfo.getItems().isEmpty()) {
        itemWithNotEmptyItems.add(groupItemInfo);
    }
});
```

Using `Stream`, you can filter from `result` then collect to a list

```
List<MyItemsData> result = new ArrayList<>();
List<MyItemsData> itemWithNotEmptyItems = result.stream()
        .filter(groupItemInfo -> !groupItemInfo.getItems().isEmpty())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I tried the above code as you had suggested, but it is not adding the elements from other objects whose type!=null in the first object with type=null. Instead it is not showing the object with type=null value in the list as shown in the image added in the edited section. @azro

Answer (score 1):

Modify your MyItemsData as below,

1. Implement equal and hash code, compare only type since uniqueness depends on the type.
2. Implement method to return boolean status of MyItemsData (return false if type is null or items is empty"

Sample MyItemsData class:

```
public static final class MyItemsData {
        private String type;
        private List items;

        public String getType() {
            return type;
        }

        public List getItems() {
            return items;
        }

        public boolean isValid() {
            return null != type && !type.isEmpty() && null != items && !items.isEmpty();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) {
                return true;
            }
            if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
                return false;
            }

            MyItemsData that = (MyItemsData) o;

            return type != null ? type.equals(that.type) : that.type == null;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return type != null ? type.hashCode() : 0;
        }
    }
```

then you can use stream to filter and get distinct data as list.

Code :

```
List<MyItemsData> result = source.stream().filter(MyItemsData::isValid).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I wanted to try without overriding equals and hashcode as i only have the service logic and the model class i should not change. @Chamly Idunil

Answer (score 1):

Let's define a class (to make it clear what we do):

```java
public class MyItemsData {

    public static class GroupItemInfo {

        private String type;
        private List<Item> items;

        public String getType() {
            return type;
        }

        public List<Item> getItems() {
            return items;
        }

        public static class Item {}

    }

}
```

And then you can define the custom comparator for `MyItemsData.GroupItemInfo.Item`. And then using `Stream` you can create a `TreeSet` to retrieve unique items using a given comparator. Then you can build a `List`.

```java
public static void main(String... args) {
    List<MyItemsData.GroupItemInfo> itemsList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<MyItemsData.GroupItemInfo.Item> uniqueItems = getUniqueItems(itemsList);
}

public static List<MyItemsData.GroupItemInfo.Item> getUniqueItems(List<MyItemsData.GroupItemInfo> items) {
    final Comparator<MyItemsData.GroupItemInfo.Item> comparator = (one, two) -> {
        // TODO implement comparator (return =0 for equal items)
        return 0;
    };

    return new ArrayList<>(items.stream()
                                .filter(item -> item.getType() != null)
                                .filter(item -> !item.getItems().isEmpty())
                                .map(MyItemsData.GroupItemInfo::getItems)
                                .flatMap(List::stream)
                                .collect(Collectors.toCollection(() -> new TreeSet<>(comparator))));
}
```

Comment: Please see the post above edited and added the entire java class for more clarity